how to forward proxy from yarp to tor
Client(http) <-> yarp(reverseProxy) <-> pproxy(http) <-> tor(socks5)
i have tor proxy server with socks5 protocol and use pproxy for send http request to socks5
i want forwarding  yarp http request -> pproxy -> to tor
is it possible? or no
yarp-program config:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.MapReverseProxy();
app.Map("/", () =>
{
    return "Yarp is working...";
});
app.Run();

yarp-appsetting.json:
{
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "r0": {
        "ClusterId": "accountApi-cluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "accountApi-cluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "d0": {
            "Address": "http://192.168.1.2:8070"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

pproxy- script:
pproxy -l http://0.0.0.0:8070 -ur socks5://127.0.0.1:9100

yarp- exception log:
info: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[9]
      Proxying to http://192.168.1.2:8070/api HTTP/2 RequestVersionOrLower
warn: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[48]
      RequestCanceled: The request was canceled before receiving a response.
      System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.<SendAsync>g__SendAsyncWithTelemetry|6_0(HttpMessageHandler handler, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpMessageInvoker httpClient, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, HttpTransformer transformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

